# Push object to empty array after condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've created a couple of services that grab data from a REST API. These services return objects with names, ids, and some unique keys pertaining to a `foo` or a `bar` name. I also have a service doing the same for businesses, also with names, ids, and what `foo`/`bar` is tied to that business.

Unfortunately, the data model for this is...not ideal. Rather than just showing which `foo`/`bar` is attached to that business, it has every single `foo` or `bar` for every single business with a `published: true/false` key/val pair.

What I'm attempting to do is grab the URL name, loop through my `foo` object, check to see if the name from the current URL and the data match, and if they do store that object in `$scope.results`. From here, I want to loop through my businesses object and check to see if its `conditionData` id matches that of the new `$scope.results` array's id. Once this condition is met, I want to store those businesses in a `$scope.businesses` array. As it stands right now, I'm getting all businesses returned, rather than just the ones that have the same id as the current `$scope.results` id. I suspect the issue is either a) I'm a noob (most likely) or b) the `published: true/false` is creating issues.

Thanks in advance for any help, let me know if I need to clarify anything else. I'm still pretty new to Angular and JS as a whole, so I'm not sure if how I'm attempting to do this is super optimal. I'm open to better ideas if anyone has any.

```
.controller('ResultsController', function($scope, $location, getData) { 
    $scope.businesses = [];
    $scope.results = [];

    var url = $location.path().split('/')[2];    // we do this because it's always going to follow a pattern of /:base/:name

    function init() {

        getData.getConditions().success(function(data) {
            var tempCondition = data;
            var tempData;

            for (var condition in tempCondition) {
                tempData = tempCondition[condition];
                if (url === tempData.name) {
                    $scope.results = tempData;
                }
            }
        })  
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('err: ' + data);
        });

        getData.getBusinesses().success(function(data) {
            var tempBusinesses = data,
                tempConditionData;

            for (var business in tempBusinesses) {
                tempConditionData = tempBusinesses[business].conditionData;

                for (var condition in tempConditionData) {
                    if (tempConditionData[condition].id === $scope.results.id) {
                        $scope.businesses.push(tempBusinesses[business]);
                    }   
                }
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('err: ' + data);
        });

    }

    init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself using SO as a rubber duck most of the time, I figured it out basically as soon as I finished typing the question. It was due to the `published: true/false` key/val pair.

All I had to do was change

```
for (var condition in tempConditionData) {
    if (tempConditionData[condition].id === $scope.results.id) {
        $scope.businesses.push(tempBusinesses[business]);
    }   
}
```

to

```
for (var condition in tempConditionData) {
    if (tempConditionData[condition].id === $scope.results.id && tempConditionData[condition].published === true ) {
        $scope.businesses.push(tempBusinesses[business]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: _using SO as a rubber duck_ I should probably be asking this over on the English StackExchange but what does it mean to use something as a rubber duck?

Comment: Basically, you explain what you're trying to do, what you've tried to do, and what the expected result is in detail to a literal rubber duck (or any object) and then your brain works out the details and comes up with different ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The two http calls you are using may also be problematic as they depend one each other. what if the first calls takes some time, your second http call returns first.

Comment: Yeah, that's another thing I'll have to go over to make it more optimal. Do you have any suggestions?  EDIT: disregard, that doesn't pertain to my question. That's a separate topic for another time.